# PHP: Make a string upper case but not the html entities in it?

Tags: php, html, html-entities

How can I make the content in a string to upper case but not the html entities in it? Is it possible?

```
$str = 'FUNDA&ensp;MENTALISM';
echo strtoupper($str);
```

I want to produce this,

```
'FUNDA MENTALISM'
```

but I get this with `strtoupper()`

```
'FUNDA&ENSP;MENTALISM'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know you haven't listed CSS in your tags, but most of the time it is easier to leave this to the client side (if you only intended this string for browser display).

Applying CSS `text-transform: uppercase;` will do this for you.

Comment: The only disadvantage is that it won't help you solve the same issue in the title tag

Answer (score 3):

Well, remove the entities and use a multi-byte character set!

```
$string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
$string = mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_UPPER, 'UTF-8');
```

Then output the string.  There's no need for most html entities, just use the native characters and set the output of the document properly.

If you really must use the entities, a regex is in order:

```
$callback = function($match) {
    return strtoupper($match[1]);
}
$regex = '/(\w+(?=&)|(?<=;)\w+)/';
$string = preg_replace_callback($regex, $callback, $string);
```

Note that I haven't tested that regex, but it should work since it's looking for letters that are not immediately followed by a `;` character...

Comment: I think that regex should be $regex = '/\w+(?=&)|(?<=;)\w+/' as it looks for characters fallowed by & or characters that are proceeded by ;. I also think that index in $match[1] should be $match[0]?

Comment: @Marcin: Thanks, I've edited that regex in.  And I meant `[1]`, but I also meant to wrap the original character class in a sub-pattern...

Answer (score 2):

I cannot use the CSS variant by kapa, 'cause I need this for the title tag. The solution provided by ircmaxell might be right, but since some servers don't have `mbstring` extension, this solution might be better:

```
echo htmlentities(strtoupper(html_entity_decode($str)));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to convert string to uppercase first than decode than you will get desired result

```
$var=<i>This</i><u>is</u><b>test</b><br>New line
```

function uppercase `strtoupper($var);`  Output will be

```
<I>THIS</I><U>IS</U><B>TEST</B><BR>NEW LINE
```

function htmlEntities() `$var=htmlEntities($var);` OUTPUT:

```
&lt;I&gt;THIS&lt;/I&gt;&lt;U&gt;IS&lt;/U&gt;&lt;B&gt;TEST&lt;/B&gt;&lt;BR&gt;NEW LINE
```

FINAL Encoding `$var=html_entity_decode($var);` 
output:

*THIS*IS**TEST**
NEW LINE

If first htmlentities convert than upper case; decode will fail as encoded test changed to uppercase and function failed;

Answer (score 0):

I created this function to replace "strtoupper" without any problem for accented letters. It works better than html_entity_decode > strtoupper > htmlentities , which did not handle certain characters (Ò) :

```
function EnMajuscule($Texte) {
    $Texte = strtoupper($Texte);
    $Texte = preg_replace_callback('#&([A-Z])([A-Z]{2,5});#',function($a){ return '&'.$a[1].strtolower($a[2]).';'; },$Texte);
    return $Texte;
}
```